# Why do people say "I am broke" instead of "I am broken"?

Tags: word-choice

I know these are correct:

> I am done.
>
> He is chosen.
>
> My phone is broken.

---

But why do we say

> I am broke.

instead of

> I am broken.

Is that even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In *formal* English both are quite grammatical, but they mean something different:

> I am broken.

This means I am injured or in bad shape in some way.

> I am broke.

This means that I have no money.

---

In colloquial speech, and even dialectic (informal) writing, some people do use *broke* in place of *broken*:

> I'm all broke up about it.

It's similar to *shook* being used in place of *shaken*:

> I'm all shook up.

This is understood and acceptable idiomatically, but it's not something that would be appropriate in a formal context.

Formally, the last two example sentences should be:

> I'm all broken up about it.
>   I'm all shaken up.

---

Note that *broke* (see Merriam-Webster's [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broke)) ***is*** the past tense of the verb *break*, and it can be used correctly in a formal context:

> The chair broke.

But it's not an adjective. The only defined adjective *broke* is the one that means without money.

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe when you say `I am broke`, the `broke` here is not the past tense of `break`, just a homonym of it. Like `record`(verb) and `record`(noun).

Comment: @HaoWu Yes, it can be frustrating when an identically spelled word actually has different meanings. We can only tell from context.

Comment: Don't forget _I'm (all) shook._

Comment: @HaoWu The word *broke* meaning "out of money" does originally derive from *break* (when someone's business or other financial venture was broken), but that's been so long almost no one remembers.

Comment: @HaoWu _record_ (verb) and _record_ (noun) are not exact homonyms. The verb has stress on the second syllable and the noun has stress on the first syllable.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: So what IS the proper term for two words that are spelled alike but have different meanings?  As e.g. I read this post today, I read other posts yesterday.

Comment: @jamesqf Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym. There are many possibilities depending on your case. _read_ (present tense) and _read_ (past tense) would be polysemes. The previous example would be heteronyms.

Comment: @jamesqf The precise term for words which are spelled alike but have different meaning is homographs. There is some inconsistency in exactly what "homonym" means, since some define it to be a word where *either* spelling or pronunciation is the same, whereas others require *both*. FWIW my (Collins) desk dictionary gives only the former definition.

Comment: For an example of the colloquial usage of "broke" meaning "broken", see the line "I feel so broke up" in the song Sloop John B (Beach Boys version)

Comment: @EspeciallyLime The spelling the same "homonym" is clearly a homonym of the pronunciation the same "homonym".  Obviously.  (To learners: this is a joke)

Comment: Using "broke" as an adjective may be formally defined, but that's (coincidentally) different from being acceptable in formal contexts. I've never thought about the difference before seeing this answer, and perhaps ELL'ers would be confused by the distinction.

Comment: Note about formality - within the realm of standard, non-slang, non-dialect words, some are more formal than others. "Broke" has a slightly informal ring to it, although you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 17):

"I am broke" doesn't refer to being broken. It's an informal way of saying that someone doesn't have any money left.

e.g. - "I can't order pizza today, I'm broke."

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broke)

Comment: You have it backwards. The use of *broke* as an adjective to mean not having any money is ***not*** slang. It's a [well-defined word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broke#h2). But saying *I am broke* to say that you're broken ***is*** slang and it ***does*** refer to being broken when used in that way.

Comment: @JasonBassford My bad - I meant that 'broke' is a colloquialism, or is informal. I've never seen anyone say 'I'm all broke up', although maybe I'm just not following the right twitters

Comment: @Tim [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/broke_1) and [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broke) say otherwise. I'm sorry I couldn't find the OED entry

Comment: @JasonBassford: The relevant definition in the full OED is **broke**  3 **slang** - *In predicative use = **broken** adj.; ruined financially, bankrupt; (often less seriously) penniless*. Maybe different people have different ideas about what "slang" means. Me, I'm with the OED here.